# "Wrong ufstype may corrupt your filesystem" - Should I be worried?

Tags: kernel, syslog, data-loss, ufs

I was just now looking through `/var/log/syslog` and I found these line which worried me:

```
ufs: You didn't specify the type of your ufs filesystem
May  5 09:06:09 Bath-Towel kernel: [  425.626221] 
May  5 09:06:09 Bath-Towel kernel: [  425.626221] mount -t ufs -o ufstype=sun|sunx86|44bsd|ufs2|5xbsd|old|hp|nextstep|nextstep-cd|openstep ...
May  5 09:06:09 Bath-Towel kernel: [  425.626221] 
May  5 09:06:09 Bath-Towel kernel: [  425.626221] >>>WARNING<<< Wrong ufstype may corrupt your filesystem, default is ufstype=old
```

What is it, what does it mean, and what should I do about it (if anything)? If more information is needed to answer my question, please just comment and I will provide it.

---

**OS Information:**

```
Description:    Ubuntu 15.04
Release:    15.04
```

Comment: It would be nice if instead of just downvoting if people could actually say what is wrong and what information needs to be added.

Comment: +1 but maybe ">>>WARNING<<< "?

Comment: The log entries spell it out pretty clearly, IMHO: One of the file systems you've got mounted (harddisk partitons, flash drives, cd-rom, dvds or whatnot) is formatted as [UFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_File_System). But UFS comes in several types, and you didn't provide which of those your file system is. You need to add the option `ufstype=whichevertype` to the mount info for that file system.  Chances are that info's coming from your fstab.  Check your file systems and their types with `df -T` on the command line.

Comment: @HenningKockerbeck I have no mounted file system which is formatted as UFS.

Comment: I have the same "problem" and would love to see this answered. I do notice that these message begin after new a new kernel is installed with `apt-get upgrade`. They go away when I reboot.

Comment: Could this be `grub` related?

Comment: Is this a description of the problem? : https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1374759

Comment: @Mausy5043: I think so as those are more or less the same errors I see.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This message could be generated when the user or a script runs the update-grub script, which would explain why you get it after kernel update. From what i understood, update-grub tries to dynamically find all the possible partitions and operating systems in them for generating the most complete grub.conf file. one of the options(one of the last ones actually) that update-grub tries for mounting an unknown partition, is ufs. This is a bug however as it could be misleading and confuse the user.

More info: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1374759

Answer (score 1):

I got this error and I fixed it updating to kernel 3.19.0-26. I think it was some bug in 3.19.0-25.

Comment: If you could find a link to the bug report where it was reported as fixed then I would be happy to accept this answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit "me too" but I saw this during a different kernel upgrade to 4.2 (most recent at time of writing)

Seems some installation code (acer recovery partition) tries to mount all partitions including a partition that should not be mounted /dev/sda4 which is an extended partition block created to have more than 4 partitions on a disk.   Its not just UFS, the script tries to mount it as ext4, fat, and some others, each have a different error message, only the UFS error message looks a bit scary.

So I think this is a cosmetic issue and the messages can be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

This may happen, for example, when you attach a FreeBSD installation image to a virtual machine using `virt-manager` (or the like). The FreeBSD image has a partition with UFS on it and when it gets attached (as a loopback device, e.g. with `losetup`) on the host, it will get scanned for filesystems by `udev` and friends. UFS may be discovered at that point.

As a side note, this^^^ only happens with raw ISO images treated as loopback devices, **not** with QCOW2 images preferred for writable (and trimmable) storage. (Reading QCOW2 as a block device would require [a conversion or a `nbd` setup](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/268460/how-to-mount-qcow2-image/506399).)

Usually `lsblk -pf` can help reveal where exactly the UFS may be.